# How to get the sum of Alike Terms in a mathematical equation string using Distributive Law

Tags: jquery, regex, string, math, match

I have creating program for solving the equation.In my first step separate the alphabets  and adding same alphabets  values.
    In my equation like:- `10x+9k-12k-3a-8a=100` alphabets present anything between `A-Z`.In my question is how to separate the alphabets.And adding the same alphabets numeric value .i need a answer like from the equation.`separate the x(10),k(9,-12),a(3,-8)`

```
    `value of x=10;
     value of k=-3;
     value of a=-11;`
```

please help me or give any suggestion and idea's.thanks

Comment: value of `a` should be `-11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a parser for you, you can tweak it as you like

```js
var str = '10x+9k-12k-3a-8a=100';
var reg = /([\-+])?\s*(\d+)?([a-z])/g;
var store = {};

function evaluateExp(){
  
  var res = reg.exec(str);
  while(res){
    
    if(!store[res[3]]){
      store[res[3]] = [];
    }

    store[res[3]].push({
        sign: res[1] || '+',
        multiplier: (typeof res[2] != 'undefined') ? parseInt(res[2], 10) : 1
    });
    res = reg.exec(str);
  }
  
  
  Object.keys(store).forEach(function(key){
    
    let val = 0;
    
    store[key].forEach(function(occ){
      if(occ.sign == '+')
        val += occ.multiplier;
      else
        val -= occ.multiplier;
    });
    
    $('ul#results').append('<li>value of '+ key +"="+ val + ';</li>');
  });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  evaluateExp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="results" style="list-style-type:none;"><ul>
```

Comment: its working great awesome.Thank u soo much.Can  you please explain the evaluateExp() function

Comment: thanks for the feedback, glad to hear that. First i'm extracting all the `(sign)(digits)(variable)`  groups with the help of that regex and store `(sign)(digits)` object for every matching group in an `array` inside store with the `key` being the `variable`.  Then I start to evalutate by looping over keys of the `store` object which are our `varibale alphabets`. For every alphabet there can be multiple expression that we just stored, so I loop over every occurence and evalute by using the `sign` that we also defined.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation.Its a more valuable one.

Comment: ` store[res[3]].push({ sign: res[1] || '+', multiplier: (typeof res[2] != 'undefined') ? parseInt(res[2], 10) : 1`    and     `if(!store[res[3]]){ store[res[3]] = [];` please tell why we use numeric values like res[3] ,res[2],& (parseInt(res[2],10):1 can u tell me what's the reason.sorry i am a beginner so i don't have basic for that. And give any basics links or reference for that..thank you. – prasanth sadhana 5 mins ago

Comment: every `res =  reg.exec(str)` gives an array of matching groups defined in `reg` RegeEx. A group is defined by `()` paranthesis. So in `res`, we only need index 1,2,3 values. you can read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) and [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/regular-expressions-methods#regexp-exec-str-regexp-exec) for more understanding.